# Unable to background a Python Flask Service via SubProcess library

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, subprocess, nohup

I am trying to background a Python Flask based service via nohup on a redhat linux server, using the subprocess library and here is the issue:

I have a python flask service at location: `/home/user/service_location`
Name of service: `service.py`

I have to start this service from another python file on the same server.
Location of the *starter script*: `/home/user/service_regen`
Name of this script: `restart_services.py`

After spending much time on it, here is what is inside `restart_services.py` now:

```py
working_directory = '/home/user/service_location'
command = 'nohup python service.py &'
ps = subprocess.Popen([command], cwd=working_directory, shell=True, stdout=open('/dev/null', 'w'), stderr=open('logfile.log', 'a'))

stdout, stderr = ps.communicate()
print("stdout: {}, stderr: {}".format(str(stdout),str(stderr)))
```

But this still seems to not start the service!
I am open to any other solution/alternative also if a feasible solution in subprocess does not exist.
Also, the output of the command does not matter to me, so you don't need to provide any solution for that. Just that I want the service to be started and backgrounded via nohup using Python.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be due to the command you send in, or the absolute path.
Such operation works on my side, please try out :

```
import os
import subprocess
import shlex

working_directory = '/home/user/service_location'
ab_path = os.path.abspath(working_directory)
command = 'nohup python service.py &'
args = shlex.split(command) # use shlex to parse the command
ps = subprocess.Popen(args, cwd=ab_path, shell=True, stdout=open('/dev/null', 'w'), stderr=open('logfile.log', 'a'))

stdout, stderr = ps.communicate()
print("stdout: {}, stderr: {}".format(str(stdout),str(stderr)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply @Jeffrey. However, this solution still seems to not start my service. Maybe, my strong guess is, when we manually type in `nohup python service.py &` in the terminal, we have to also give that extra *Enter* command for which nohup replies with: `nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'`. Maybe this is the reason behind the failure? If it is, how do we deal with that *Enter* command in subprocess?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after putting in 5 hours into it. Here is what a senior of mine came up with which is now working!

```py
command = 'nohup python3.6 service.py &'
```

The exact reasons of this working are not clear to us at the moment. Maybe it has got to do something with python distributions and PATHs in this particular server. (because, the above posted code seemed to work just fine in one of our dev servers). Strangely, both servers have the *same* distribution installed via the same way!

```sh
Python 3.6.0 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec XX XXXX, 12:22:00)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```